# Как лучше реализовать подсказки для инпутов и как лучше реализовать закрытие окна на js?

Tags: javascript, css

Здравствуйте. Есть таких два вопроса:

1 вопрос) Есть такая верстка invizmachine.esy.es/templatemonster/ по клику на кнопку 'Sign Up' появляется окно. Нужно сделать всплывающие подсказки у инпутов так как на этом изображении, которое я прикрепил.

[image: подсказки инпутов]

я не пойму как сделать чтобы ширина у этих подсказок, сама подстраивалась, в зависимости от того сколько в них текста. у меня сейчас там все они одинакового размера, но нужно сделать чтобы были разные, как на изображении.

2 вопрос) Как мне это лучше реализовать на чистом js, чтобы кликая вне выпадающего блока 'sign-up__dropdown' он закрывался. На jquery это не составляло труда, а вот на чистом js все никак не могу додумать как это сделать. именно с реализацией проблемы.

Буду очень благодарен если поможете.

Comment: Ну а вы начните с реализации на jquery (раз вы знаете как). А потом сделайте downgrade и просто перефразируйте jquery функции на js.

Comment: @alexoander та в том то и дело что не совсем понимаю как. можете с логикой самой подсказать ? возможно из-за того что не совсем понимаю как оно должно работать, не могу реализовать это.

Comment: Насчет резиновости подсказок - попробуйте добавить `_width:200px; min-width:200px ` в стили. Логика такая - блок не может быть меньше чем 200px но может быть больше и потому должен тянуться. Проблема будет только в том, чтобы он тянулся влево, а не по умолчанию

Comment: @alexoander не помог ваш способ. Я сделал через white-space: nowrap, убрал и min-width и просто width. И все работает как надо, как считаете нормальный способ ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Чтобы подскасказки были в одну строку, нужно задать для класса `error-message__text` CSS-свойство `white-space` со значением `nowrap`. Оно предотвратит перенос на новую строку.
2. Тут есть несколько вариантов. Вот 2 из них:

   1. Можно создать элемент во весь экран, поверх которого будет форма, и ловить клики для закрытия на него.

      Вот так будет выглядить структура:

      ```
      <div class="sign-up">
        <a href="#" class="sign-up__link"></a>
        <div class="sign-up__dropdown"></div>
        <div class="sign-up__overlay"></div>
      </div>
      ```

      Это примерные стили:

      ```
      .sign-up__link{
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
      }
      .sign-up__overlay{
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
      }
      .sign-up__dropdown{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 3;
      }
      ```

      Теперь на `.sign-up__overlay` можно повесить обработчик, который будет закрывать dropdown:

      ```
      document.querySelector('.sign-up__overlay').addEventListener(() => {
          // Здесь можно выполнить код закрытия
      })
      ```

      Так же нужно не забыть, что теперь нужно показывать и скрывать не только `dropdown`, но и `overlay`
   2. Это вариант аналогичен привычному решению на jQuery:

      ```
      document.querySelector('.sign-up__dropdown').addEventListener('click', e => {
          e.stopPropagation() // Останавливаем "размножение" ("всплытие") события, т.е. оно будет сработано только при клике на этот элемент или его потомков, и будет проигнорированно для элементов выше.
          console.log('click on dropdown')
      })
      document.addEventListener('click', e => {
          console.log('click on document, OUTSIDE!')
      })
      ```

Comment: Второй вариант реализации окна всплывающего хорош, только можете еще подсказать.Как мне теперь закрыть это окно, по клику в не его. Я думал сделать как-то так. https://jsfiddle.net/13skgxe2/ (тут чисто js код)но не работает оно, голова что-то совсем не варит, у меня всегда были проблемы с этими окнами всплывающими на js

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bbx2g72v/ вот этот код будет более полным. Т.е. нужно останавливать вскрытие не только на dropdown, но и на link (либо сразу sign-up, как в примере), иначе клик на link будет сразу закрывать dropdown. Плюс при закрытие из вне нужно убирать еще и класс у ссылки.

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь!